# Perl script+Remove all lines except the one's starting with "Only in"

Tags: perl

I have a file which has many lines. A few of those start with "Only in". So I want to retain only the lines which start with "Only in" and delete the rest. Can someone please tell me what regex command I could use.

Something like " %s/!(Only in)/rm -rf that line " Sorry for mixing up verilog, unix and perl here. Can someone help me with the same

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -ne 'print if /^Only in /' file
```

See also `grep`.

Comment: In that case, see also `perldoc -f grep` :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -i -ne '/^Only in/ and print' file
```

And in a script :

```
use strict; use warnings;

$INPLACE_EDIT = 1;

while (<>) {
    /^Only in/ and print;
}
```

Both the 2 solutions replace inline without the need of creating temporary files by yourself.

Comment: Am I reading this wrong or are you keeping and deleting the wrong lines? I think the `or` should be an `and`.

Comment: Instead of printing how do I overwrite that file?

Comment: Like this : `perl -i -ne '/^Only in/ and print' file`

Comment: Also just curious to know the otherway round. How do I retain all other lines except Only in if I were to modify the above command